# How can I use LINQ to add a Where clause to a Tuple to return a single value in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have a Tuple defined like so:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, double>> myList
```

Now I want to extract the 'double' value when string1 matches a certain value and string 2 matches a certain value. I tried something like this, but it didn't work. Any tips are appreciated.

```
myList.Select(t => t.Item3).Where(t => t.Item1 = "test" && t.Item2 = "query");
```

This treats 't' as a double, and complains that double does not have an Item1 property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the order of `Where` and `Select` backwards:

```
myList.Where(t => t.Item1 == "test" && t.Item2 == "query")
      .Select(t => t.Item3);
```

`Select` *transforms* the item. In this case, on the left side going in you have an enumeration of `Tuple<string, string, double>` and the coming out on the right side is an enumeration of `double`.

Additionally, you've got `=` where you mean `==`...

Comment: I tried this... The error now is ''Property or indexer Tuple<string, string, double>.Item1 cannot be assigned to, it is read only". Apparently it thinks the '=' sign means trying to assign a value. I replaced it with '==', the error now is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>' to 'double'"

Comment: Coming out of the select is still an `IEnumerable<double>`. If you expect only one matching entry and want that, you need to call `Single()`.

Comment: I realized my mistake and used First(). Is Single() better or comparable? Marking answer as the right one.

Comment: Well, `First()` will give you the first item one regardless of how many are in the enumeration, and `Single()` returns the first item and additional throws if there is another item after that. IMHO, if you expect only one item you should use `Single()` to make sure the collection has only one element and you're not silently throwing data away / ignoring a bug.

Comment: If you are very sure that it is single entry, use `SingleOrDefault` else I suggest `FirstOrDefault`